# how to exclude data by date filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

i need to implement below logic

​Exclude the patients where patient date is on or 1 day prior to event date :

```
select patient,[patient date], [event date] 
from stu_tbl 
where [patient date] <> DATEADD(d, - 1, [event date]) and 
      [patient date] <> [event date];
```

patients date will be multiple

will the above condition work?

Comment: it should work, although it might be a bit difficult to read

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using non-standard SQL) Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like you want

```
select patient,
           [patient date],
           [event date]
           from stu_tbl
           where [patient date] >= DATEADD(d, - 1, [event date])
                      and [patient date] < cast([event date] AS date);
```

Answer (score 0):

for add multiple patients date you can use IN operator
in where condition.
like as

```
select patient,[patient date], [event date] 
from stu_tbl 
where [patient date] NOT IN (patient date1, patient date2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    select patient,
       [patient date],
       [event date]
       from stu_tbl
       where [patient date] NOT IN (DATEADD(d, - 1, [event date]), [event date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select patient,[patient date], [event date] 
from stu_tbl 
where DateDiff(Day, [patient date], [event date]) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility that your dates have a time component.  If so:

```
select patient, [patient date], [event date] 
from stu_tbl 
where [patient date] <  dateadd(day, -1, cast([event date] as date)) or 
      [patient date] >= dateadd(day, 1, cast([event date] as date));
```